# SQL multiple results on one row when only one column has different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a similar query to this one..

```
select i.App_Id                       as ApplicationId, 
         Cast(i.ObjectId as NVARCHAR(50)) as ObjectId, 
         1                  as ActivityId, 
         Cast(case 
                when oh.ObjectId is null then 0 
                else 1 
              end as BIT)               as Highlight, 
         iu.UserId                      as UserId
  from   table0 i 
         inner join table1 iu 
                 on i.IdeaID = iu.IdeaID
         left join table2 oh 
                on oh.ObjectId = i.IdeaID 
         left join table3 mIS 
                on i.IdeaID = mIS.IdeaID 
                   AND mIS.EndTime is null 
         inner join table4 mISF 
                 on mISF.StateFluxId = mIS.StateFluxId 
  where  (iu.RelationId = 1 or iu.RelationId = 2)
```

which is returning, for example:

```
2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2
2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3
```

I'm trying to change it in order to merge the results of the 5th column when the other column values are the same:

```
2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1,2,3
```

Is this possible? Didn't manage to accomplish it using the Stuff function..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I have added the XML PATH ()  .Please do necessary changes according to your requirement

```
select i.App_Id                       as ApplicationId, 
             Cast(i.ObjectId as NVARCHAR(50)) as ObjectId, 
             1                  as ActivityId, 
             Cast(case 
                    when oh.ObjectId is null then 0 
                    else 1 
                  end as BIT)               as Highlight, 
               stuff(
      (
      SELECT ',' + CAST(IU.USERID  AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                    FROM table1 t2 WHERE iu.IdeaID = t2.IdeaID 
                                     FOR XML PATH('')
      )
                                                ,1,1,'')    AS USERID
      from   table0 i 
             inner join table1 iu 
                     on i.IdeaID = iu.IdeaID
             left join table2 oh 
                    on oh.ObjectId = i.IdeaID 
             left join table3 mIS 
                    on i.IdeaID = mIS.IdeaID 
                       AND mIS.EndTime is null 
             inner join table4 mISF 
                     on mISF.StateFluxId = mIS.StateFluxId 
      where  (iu.RelationId = 1 or iu.RelationId = 2) 
      GROUP BY  i.App_Id  
                ,i.ObjectId,
                oh.ObjectId
```

Comment: What is t1 ? iu i guess

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this,

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.App_Id AS ApplicationId
    ,Cast(i.ObjectId AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS ObjectId
    ,1 AS ActivityId
    ,Cast(CASE 
            WHEN oh.ObjectId IS NULL
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END AS BIT) AS Highlight
    ,
    --iu.UserId                      as UserId
    (stuff(SELECT ',' + userid FROM table1 WHERE Ideaid = iu.IdeaId FOR XML path(''), 1, 1, '')) AS UserId
FROM table0 i
INNER JOIN table1 iu ON i.IdeaID = iu.IdeaID
LEFT JOIN table2 oh ON oh.ObjectId = i.IdeaID
LEFT JOIN table3 mIS ON i.IdeaID = mIS.IdeaID
    AND mIS.EndTime IS NULL
INNER JOIN table4 mISF ON mISF.StateFluxId = mIS.StateFluxId
WHERE (
        iu.RelationId = 1
        OR iu.RelationId = 2
        )
```